# Can I generate collision boxes from a model file with BepuPhysics and XNA?

Tags: xna, models

I am currently developing a game using BepuPhysics in XNA 4.0, and I am trying to reasonably match the in game collision Entities with the Model they are associated with.

My current workflow involves guessing what size the various segments of the model are, guessing a size and position of a box to match each segment, and throwing stuff at it to see if I'm right.

This is not an efficient process.

Is there a way to automatically generate the Entity from the Model? 
If not, is there some other way to speed up my workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very late, but just use the TriangleMesh class. In the future, I highly recommend the [BEPU Forums](http://www.bepu-games.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=4) for questions like this.